# How to set color in td with thymeleaf?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I tried if `object.qtdItem == 0`, then set the color to red for the TD:

```
<td th:style="${obj.qtdItem == 0 ? 'color: red;'}" th:text="${obj.text}"></td>
```

but this happened

```
error: Caused by:
org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelParseException: Expression
[perfil.qtdItem == 0 ? 'red'] @38: EL1044E: Unexpectedly ran out of
input
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The ternary statement needs an `else` clause e.g.

```
<td th:style="${obj.qtdItem == 0 ? 'color: red;' : 'color: some_other_color;'}}" th:text="${obj.text}"></td>
```

Comment: Or much better if you are using the newer Thymeleaf: `th:style="${obj.qtdItem == 0 ? 'color: red;' : _ }}"` see the `_` for an no action else clause

Answer (score 0):

Another option:

```
th:style="|${obj.qtdItem == 'red' ? 'color: red;' : 'color: green;'}|"
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me.

```
th:style="|${obj.qtdItem == 'red' ? 'color: red;' : 'color: green;'}|"
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.